# How to export csv as a zip file in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, csv

I am to create a `CSV` and write information to it and then download it.Now I have to download it as a zip format.

```
 public  void WriteToCSV(List<DeviceModel> DeviceList)
    {
        string attachment = "attachment; filename=DeviceModel.csv";
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
        Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
        Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");
        WriteColumnName();
        foreach (DeviceModel Device in DeviceList)
        {
            WriteDeviceInfo(Device);
        }
      Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/04/aspnet-download-multiple-files-as-zip.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library for that :

http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/